# How to sort data on the basis of time from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services

I have a table named "User_Records" in that I have a column which is "created_by". I want to sort the records on the basis of this filter. I am very new to AWS and have looked on the internet but didn't got any solution for that. Please share your ideas as I am heavily stucked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Local Secondary Index to achieve your usecase. Please refer to the link below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Using

Thanks,
Rohan